# How to override a TypeScript interface without extending?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using a library (vue-i18n) that defines the following in its `types/index.d.ts` file (trimmed for brevity):

```
declare class VueI18n {
  t(key: VueI18n.Path, values?: VueI18n.Values): VueI18n.TranslateResult;
  t(key: VueI18n.Path, locale: VueI18n.Locale, values?: VueI18n.Values): VueI18n.TranslateResult;
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $t: typeof VueI18n.prototype.t;
  }
}
```

I don't like that the `t` function returns a `TranslateResult` and would like to override it (in place, not via extension) so it returns a string.

I tried creating my own `declarations.d.ts` file in my project:

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $t(key: VueI18n.Path, values?: VueI18n.Values): string;
    $t(
      key: VueI18n.Path,
      locale: VueI18n.Locale,
      values?: VueI18n.Values
    ): string;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't like this.

```
[ts] Duplicate identifier '$t'.
```

I need to do an in-place override, in other words, replace the type without extending into a new interface. How do I do this?

***EDIT:***

OK, that doesn't seem possible. Is there any way to reduce the repetitiveness of using `as string` here?

```
this.msg = this.$t('blah') as string;
this.str2 = this.$t('thisToo') as string;
this.strX = this.$t('another') as string;
this.g = this.$t('test') as string;
```

Comment: Short of using `// @ts-ignore`, you cannot.

Comment: Well, that's lame. :/ Time to put in a feature request for TS 3.x.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

> OK, that doesn't seem possible. Is there any way to reduce the repetitiveness of using as string here?

### Using a mixin to proxy $t

`test-i18n.mixin`

```
import {Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class LangMixin extends Vue {

  public t(key: string, params?: string[]) {
    return this.$t(key, params) as string;
  }
}
```

Now, in any component you can extend the mixin, and call `this.t` instead of `this.$t`: no need to cast `$t` in every call.

```
<template>
  <p>{{someStringProperty}}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Mixins, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import langMixin from './test-i18n.mixin';

@Component
export default class LangTest extends Mixins(langMixin) {

  get someStringProperty(): string {
    return this.t('global.last-name');
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using vue class components here but this will work with `Vue.extend` too. **However, if you use mixins I really suggest to use the class component api instead, or you will lose a lot of intellisense/types aid**.

(And of course, you should do the same with `$tc`).